# How can I make Express router work this way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

I'm doing a project for school, I need to create a Rest API for a blog with Node.js.
Users can post articles, and post comments related to these articles. For this project I'm using Sequelize and Express.

In my "*comments*" table, there is a "*article*" column which contains the title of the article where the comments has been posted. So I'm using a url like the following to get article's id, and then the title : `/articles/:id/comments`

The way I wanted the router's structure to be is the following :

- to post a comment -> `POST localhost/articles/:id/comments`
- to list all comments of a specific article -> `GET localhost/articles/:id/comments`
- to list all comments of the whole blog -> `GET localhost/articles/comments`

The problem is that when I make a `GET localhost/articles/comments` request, the router trigger this part of the code that leads to a Sequelize BAD_FIELD_ERROR :

*file: routes/article.js*

```js
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
    Article.findByPk(id).then((article) => {
        if (!article) res.sendStatus(404);
        else res.json(article);
    });
});
```

Instead of this part :

*file: routes/article.js*

```js
router.get("/comments", (req, res) => {
    const Query = req.query;
    Comment.findAll({
        where: Query
    }).then((comments) => res.json(comments))
});
```

This is the *server.js* file :

```js
const express = require("express");
const securityRouter = require("./routes/security");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user");
const articleRouter = require("./routes/article");
const verifyWebToken = require("./middleware/verifyWebToken");
const app = express();

const connection = require("./lib/db");
connection.sync();

app.use(express.json());

app.use("", securityRouter);
app.use("/users", userRouter);
app.use("/articles", verifyWebToken, articleRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server is listening."));
```

Comment: Express router is first match first serve.  If you have `router.get("/:id"...)` above `router.get("/comments"...)` in the file, the /comments route never been used.  Thus, put more specific route first and more generic one lower.

Comment: Thank you! It worked